# rsyslog conf file problem

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I'm running Fedora (F19) and my */var/log/messages* is filled with info coming from avahi-daemon: stuff like:

```
Jan 21 14:13:42 localhost avahi-daemon[554]: Invalid response packet from host 10.10.22.3.
```

from my local network

since I read somewhere that it's harmless, but I don't have time at the moment to debug it, I thought about disabling the reporting by modifying */etc/rsyslog.conf*.

I modified this line:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none   /var/log/messages
```

to this line

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;avahi-daemon.none   /var/log/messages
```

but with the new line rsyslog doesn't work anymore!

**systemctl restart rsyslog** reports it as running, but nothing gets ever written in *messages* - doing stuff that normally gets reported, as stopping & restarting some process (e.g. **systemctl restart cups**), nothing gets reported.

If I restore the *rsyslog.conf* line as before, the restart of cups gets reported.

Is there some problem in the way I modified that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none
```

Are traditional syslog style facility.priority pairs.  I like rsyslogd, but while it does have [documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html), those docs are idiosyncratic in form and atrociously organized<sup>1</sup> and I have no idea at what point, wading through them haphazardly, new users are supposed to learn this.  I think the presumption is you are already familiar with how traditional syslog works, which is unfortunate since those man pages won't be on a system that started out using rsyslogd.

Anyway, here's [an online `man syslog.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf) with which rsyslog should be compatible.  Note that there is a short, finite, hard-coded list of *facilities* not including "avahi-daemon".   I.e., *facility* != just some tag or label used in logging.

You can filter messages via substring matching and discard them (this is rsyslog specific):

```
:msg, contains, "avahi-daemon" ~
```

That needs to be *before* all the "Log by facility" rules, so that the message is discarded first.  The relevant scrap of documentation is [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/).

However, that matches substrings in the message, and in this case, "avahi-daemon" is actually a prepended tag (see, e.g, `-t` in `man logger`) that's not part of `msg`.  Other possible properties are listed [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html) and the [**compare-operations** here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html).  So perhaps:

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "avahi-daemon" ~
```

Will be the most effective.

There's a different method of "[filtering by program name](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Filtering_by_program_name)" in the wiki.  I don't know if that is going to be any more efficient.

---

<sup>1. Perhaps the presumption is that search engines be your primary guide...eliminating the need for any coherent organization.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I tried it immediately. I found a good reference also at http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html ... unfortunately, it doesnt work: rsyslog ignores the line (which I put before the /var/log/messages line)

Comment: got it! You only missed that avahi-daemon is not in :msg, but in :syslogtag, so the correct line is ':syslogtag, contains, "avahi-daemon" ~', and it works!

Comment: Cheers -- did not know about those distinctions!  I've edited in some stuff for posterity.